# Client side routing with Page.js and bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the [Page.js](http://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/) client side routing library to work with [Bootstrap 3 built in tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), so that my back and forward buttons in the browser navigates between routes and show the corresponding tab.

With my current code setup it works sometimes, but it behaves inconsistently. Sometimes with navigates to a visited tab, and sometimes it does not (nothing happens). My tabs are built with the Bootstrap tabs with data-toggle, so it is only using the built in Bootstrap javascript for it's default behaviour.

If someone would be able to help me make the back and forward buttons working between routes, also showing the appropriate tabs, I would be grateful!

#### Javascript

```
var page = page;

/**
 * Define routes and callbacks
 */
page('/profile', function(ctx) {
    showTab(ctx.pathname);
    console.log(ctx.pathname);

});

page('/search', function(ctx) {
   showTab(ctx);
    console.log(ctx.pathname)

});

page('/account',  function(ctx) {
    showTab(ctx.pathname);
    console.log(ctx.pathname);
});

/**
 * Visit route corresponding to the current clicked tab
 */

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
        console.log("Hello again")
        var targetView = $(e.target).attr('href')
        targetView = targetView.replace("#", "");
        page('/'+ targetView)
    })
});

/**
 * Show tab corresponding to current route/path
 */

function showTab(path) {
        path = path.toString().replace('/', '');
        var selector = '.nav-tabs a[href="#' + path + '"]'
        $(selector).tab("show");
}

//start route
page();
```

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck in the exact same situation recently! Here's how I solved it.

**The Problem**

Assume you were on `/account` then navigated to `/search` and pressed back button, which leads you to `/account`.
Following happens:

1. Page.js receives url (which is `/account`) and calls its handler, for this case:

   ```
   page('/account',  function(ctx) {
       showTab(ctx.pathname);
       console.log(ctx.pathname);
   });
   ```
2. in `showTab` following code gets executed:

   ```
   ...
   $(selector).tab("show");
   ...
   ```

   which shows the corresponding tab. So far so good...
3. `on('shown.bs.tab', ...` event gets triggered and makes this happen:

   ```
   page('/'+ targetView)
   ```

   which effectively redirects you to the same page you're on already and makes your browser move one step forward so it removes all 'forward' history.

**The Solution**

... is very simple: just check if you are already on the desired url before calling `page()` once again in `on('shown.bs.tab', ...)`, something like this:

```
if (window.location.pathname != '/' + targetView)
    page('/' + targetView)
```